Establishing that a room is not wire-tapped amongst people who might want to wire-tap it?
$k$ popes want to talk privately in a room, with no wire-tapping. The popes want to make sure the room isn't wire-tapped, but don't trust each other. Each pope has a different security guy that they trust. How can the popes make sure the room isn't wire-tapped?
If the popes send their security guys into the room in order, then the last security guy could've wire-tapped the room, and no one would know.
My guess at a solution is to randomly decide on a security guy to send in. And you keep sending a random security guard in (with replacement) for a geometric amount of security guards (e.g. any particular security guard that gets sent in will be the last one with probability $p$). The smaller $p$ is, the more reliably a security guy can't wire-tap a room without being caught by the next security guard sent in. But also, the lower the $p$ is, the more time you'll waste sending security guards in.
Is that scheme sound, and is there perhaps a much better/efficient scheme?

You need to specify the problem more precisely — can you, for example, shuffle the guys but tell everybody that they're first?

@CommandMaster I think the problem is decently well-specified. For the example you give: is there any way that $k=2$ popes, among themselves, could ever agree on the scheme you proposed? I think not.

Is there any reason why it's not possible for all the security people to go in at the same time?

@timuzhti you'd run into the same problem. Security person A checks one crevice in the room. Then Security person B checks that crevice. The security people will keep checking the crevice in turn, and there are no good guarantees that the last person to check the crevice didn't plant a wire. Or else, there's no good guarantees that the last security man to leave the room didn't toss a wire-tap somewhere.

I don't know, the constraints on this still feel somewhat artificial and the solution would seem more in line with that of a logic puzzle than what would usually be considered a cryptographic problem.

Agree with Mr. Master.  Too much unknown e.g. is the security guy trust reciprocated?
